# Joomla 2.5: passing parameters to contact form

Tags: parameter-passing, joomla2.5, contact-form

I've an adhoc component to manage vehicles and if the user wants more information about a vehicle, I want to redirect him to a contact form passing the vehicle's ID as a parameter to the form, in order to get vehicle's name and other info prior to send the mail.
How can I achieve this?
Now I'm using Fox Contact Form, but I can change it if there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the capabilities of Fox Contact Form, but we do exactly this on several auto sites using ChronoForms. This is a 2 step process. First you must decide how you are going to package the information on the originating page.

If the more info is a link, then you will need to pass the information to the form as part of the query string. Your links would have to be formed something like this:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&view=form&year=2000&make=Ford&model=Mustang
```

You can add as many parameters as you would like to pass to the form.

If the more info can be turned in to a form, then you can add hidden fields to the form that include all of the data you want to pass to the contact form.

The second part of the task is to add a bit of code to the fields in the contact form so that the items auto populate in to the form. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="year" value="<?php JRequest::getVar('year',''); ?>">
<input type="text" name="make" value="<?php JRequest::getVar('make',''); ?>">
<input type="text" name="model" value="<?php JRequest::getVar('model',''); ?>">
```

This would give you input fields that the user can then edit, but you could easily make the fields read-only or hidden fields instead of text boxes.

Comment: Many thanks Brent. It works like a charm. But I have to call the form this way: `http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=myForm&view=form&year=2000&make=Ford&model=Mustang`